# openstack network settings physical network

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon, juju

I have so far completed my **single server openstack** installation using conjure up. But now. I still fail to setup the network settings. Here is my network setup currently:

[image]

So far i tried to set up public network using my public ip to no avail. How should I setup my network so I can get floating ip from my public ip. Assume my public ip is 192.168.1.0/24, I would like to give my floating ip from range 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200

Answer (score 1):

You would need to configure your public network as a 'provider network' during openstack setup and inside your OpenStack, you need to configure the network as an external network.

Comment: "You would need to configure your public network as a 'provider network' during openstack setup" How can I accomplish this? So far if I ping my network using my router network namespace from neutron gateway container, I can ping it. And then if I do bash also using router namespace I also can ping router, but cant ping the external network gateway. I'm using lxdbr0 nat with my physical network enp3s0f0 (on the bare metal machine), and all juju container is connected using lxdbr0

Comment: I installed openstack using conjure up, so evertyhing is automatically done. There is no other setup about provider network

Answer (score 0):

And what about proxy arp and iptables?
Something like:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens160/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
```